# embed live camera view inside a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, camera

I've been trying to figure out how to embed a small(ish) live camera view inside of an iPhone's `UIView` to no avail.
I have not even been able to find any samples of that on the net either.  I know that it's do-able, but I don't even know where to start.  There seem to be a lot of examples where others have added views TO the full-blown screen view of the camera, but not the other way around...

It seems that `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` just displays the BIG modal camera
viewer, picture taker, so it is unsuitable (I think) for my purposes.

I want to have a small live camera view, inside a `UIView`, and I can add my own buttons
for taking the pic (I can probably figure this out - a delegate of some sort to capture
the image)

Thank you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your purpose you need to use [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html), specifically look at `AVCaptureSession` , `AVCaptureDeviceInput`,  which you can use in order to get access to the cameras and look into `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` which will allow you to draw the camera input to the screen, everything you need is in there..